# Do Fuling villages respawn?

Tags: valheim

After clearing out a Fuling village, it looks like a good place to set up a base as long as they don't come back.  Will the Fulings respawn after a while or is it a safe once the village is clear?

Comment: Haven’t had the chance to confirm this yet, but I’ve seen people claim if you destroy the beds, the village won’t repop; I have an A/B test in progress that were both cleared out an hour apart, but so far neither has respawned.

Comment: (That said I actually really don’t like taking over fuling villages - they’re not well defendable positions usually, and night patrols can wreck you.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on in game observations, the villages never respawn once its cleared out.  The fuling totems, however, do come back.

Comment: Moreover, there is a certain radius around player buildings (or workbenches?) where no enemies spawn. That prevents enemies from spawning inside your base.

Comment: @Chrᴉz Yes it is workbenches, not other structures.

Comment: @TylerH It's now any base structure, including most of the torches, workbench, bed, and so on. There's a full [list here](https://valheim.fandom.com/wiki/Player_base).

Answer (score 0):

My spawn has a small island with a Fuling village on it, the island takes about 30 seconds to walk across. I've cleared all enemies from the island, destroyed all the buildings and set up a large scale flax and barley farm with a couple of my own buildings on site. Whilst I am on the island Fuling patrols, random Deathsquitos and Lox herds still spawn. It seems to be on a daily basis; one or two Fulings spawn every day and if left unchecked they attack and destroy the crops.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set up a base in the Plains, your best bet is to dig a trench around a decent size portion of land next to the water, however big you want for your base, raise the ground on the edge with the trench so enemies can't walk up from the water and do the same on the water line so they can't swim up from the shore. Raise the ground to build a pier for docking ships and the only thing you will have to deal with is an occasional Deathsquito flying in to annoy you. Leaves you with no structures on the perimeter for monsters to aggro onto and attempt to destroy.

Answer (score 0):

The structures will never respawn if you destroy them. But if you just clear the village and leave it, new fulings will spawn in the same locations.

When the player builds structures (workbench, campfire, most buildings, I think), there is a certain radius where enemies will not spawn.

Your base is not safe from attacks, however. They will still spawn outside, and especially at night, come to attack since they spawn in greater numbers at night. Stone walls and moats are good defensive structures.